# Change SherlockActionBar line color dynamically

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to change the color of the bottomline of the sherlock actionbar.

[image]
But I want to change it dynamically.

When the user is offline I want it to appear red, when he is logging on I want it orange and when he is succesfully connected the line should be green.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in case anyone wants to do this.
I used [this website](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to make 3 styles and took the 'ab_transparent' resource out of the zip.

To set the actionbar on runtime I used

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_transparent_connecting));
```

Sidenote: this worked perfectly on android 4.0+ but on <4.0 I had to call

`this.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();`

after setting the backgrounddrawable for it to take effect.